# Scrapy CSV output duplicates fields

Tags: python, csv, field, scrapy

I have a spider (below) and I want to be able to run it via a Cron job every 10 days or so, however, every time I run it after the first time. It rewrite the Fields instead of just appending the items to the appropriate fields in the CSV. How can I make it so that I only have one group of field headers at the top and all the data below it no matter how many times I run it?

```
import scrapy

class Wotd(scrapy.Item):
    word = scrapy.Field()
    definition = scrapy.Field()
    sentence = scrapy.Field()
    translation = scrapy.Field()


class WotdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wotd'
    allowed_domains = ['www.spanishdict.com/wordoftheday']
    start_urls = ['http://www.spanishdict.com/wordoftheday/']
    custom_settings = {
        #specifies exported fields and their order
    'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['word','definition','sentence','translation']
    }

def parse(self, response):
    jobs = response.xpath('//div[@class="sd-wotd-text"]')
    for job in jobs:
        item = Wotd()
        item['word'] = job.xpath('.//a[@class="sd-wotd-headword-link"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['definition'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="sd-wotd-translation"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['sentence'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="sd-wotd-example-source"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['translation'] = job.xpath('.//div[@class="sd-wotd-example-translation"]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

From what I have been reading on the Scrapy docs it looks like I may have to mess around with the CsvItemExporter class and set include_headers_line=False but I am not sure where to add that class in the project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you didn't share your current project structure so it's hard to advice where to put it in your concrete example.

Let's assume your project is named `my_project`. Under the main project directory (the one which contains `settings.py`), create file `exporters.py` with this content:

```
import scrapy.exporters

class NoHeaderCsvItemExporter(scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, file, join_multivalued=', ', **kwargs):
        super(NoHeaderCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(file=file, include_headers_line=False, join_multivalued=join_multivalued, **kwargs)
```

Class `NoHeaderCsvItemExporter` inherits from standard CSV exporter, just specifies that we don't want header lines included in the output.

Next you have to specify your new exporter class for CSV format, either in `settings.py` or in spider's `custom_settings`. Following your current approach with the later option, it would be:

```
custom_settings = {
    'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['word','definition','sentence','translation'],
    'FEED_EXPORTERS': {
        'csv': 'my_project.exporters.NoHeaderCsvItemExporter',
    }
}
```

Just be aware that using this class, there won't be *any* header lines included in the CSV, not even for the first export.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I ran it one time without your changes to get the headers set and then made your changes and worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!